# How to check type of object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JSON file containing two different types of Objects in it. I want to iterate over the JSON with respect to their type. To illustrate my problem I created two different type of Object `Animal` and `Person`

Now I want to check the type of Object whether it is an Animal or Person.

```
type Animal = {
  name: string;
  legs: number;
}

type Person = {
  name: number;

}

const checkType = (isAnimalOrPerson: Animal | Person) =>{
  if(isAnimalOrPerson instanceof Animal){
     console.log("animal type");
  }
  else{

  }
}
```

Here I am getting an error on if the condition says: `"Animal" only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: `Animal` is a type, not a class. That's why `instanceof` cannot be used.

Comment: refer this https://www.georgestefanis.com/blog/2020/10/30/typescript-how-to-check-for-types.-using-tagged-unions./

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with `type` is that it's a concept that only exists during development; once you transpile, it disappears, and TypeScript can't foresee the shape of a runtime value you might pass (unless you do assertion, i.e. explicit checks about what properties an object has). If you want to do type checking, you have to do it in another way, for example using classes, and then the approach would only work if you actually instantiate the class (as opposed to just using it as a shape):

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    legs: number;
}

class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    job: string;
    education: string;
}

let a: Animal = new Animal();
let b: Animal = { name: "Rex", legs: 4, age: 3 };
let c = new Person();

function checkType(arg: Animal | Person): string {
    if (arg instanceof Animal) {
        return "This is an animal";
    } else if (arg instanceof Person) {
        return "This is a person";
    }

    return "Can't tell";
}

console.log(checkType(a)); // This is an animal
console.log(checkType(b)); // Can't tell
console.log(checkType(c)); // This is a person
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it will return true only when the object is created using that class but in my case, I have a JSON and I am iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure will this help gonna help you

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

update
i just found this  look similar to your question
https://medium.com/ovrsea/checking-the-type-of-an-object-in-typescript-the-type-guards-24d98d9119b0

Answer (score 0):

There's varoius ways to check `PersonorAnimal` value is also satisfies `Animal`.

1. coerce by property

```
if ('legs' in toBeDetermined) {
  // toBeDetermined should be `Animal` in this block
}
```

2. give `Animal` a `unique symbol` and check them

```
const animalTag: unique symbol = Symbol("Animal tag");

type Animal = {
  __brand__: typeof animalTag;
  name: string;
  legs: number;
}

if (toBeDetermined.__brand__ === animalTag) {
  // toBeDetermined can be coerced manually into Animal
}
```

I prefer 1 because `Animal` has disjoint property `legs`.